# change dropdown values with ajax and then save with postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, postback

I have a dropdown field that  has default values when page load.

after some user action the dropdown values are changing using jquery ajax.

then a postback button have to save the changes to db.

the problem is that asp.net doesn't notice that dropdown values were change and keep the old vaules as part of the postback.

my question is how can I change asp:dropdownlist with ajax and then save it on postback(I can use updae panel but I want to know if there is another way)

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"><asp:ListItem Value="0">value1</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList> 

$.ajax({

        url: "/WebServices/Service3.svc/getH",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ff: yy}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            arr = JSON.parse(data.d);
            $("#ddl1").empty();
            $('#ddl1')
               .append($("<option value='0'>arr.someNewValues</option>"));
```

Comment: Since these options are added on the `clientside` and `DropDownList` is the server side control it will not find the options added through `ajax` and thus will not get the selected `option`. So I would suggest write an `onchange` event to select on `clientside` keep a `serverside` control which is a `hiddenfield` and `onchange` set selected value to that `hiddenfield` and now you can get the `selected option`